# List View row height is not varying

Tags: android, listview, height, row

I have the following layout that seems to have different heights for each row depending if one image get resolved. The layout is defined below. Without hardcoding the layout_height. How can I ensure all fit the same height. I understand image resolution plays a role. So, It might not be doable. However, I am looking for a creative way to solve the problem.

The first image is my default avator (it is 50x50 .png file). If there is attached image for a row, It would come as 50x50 .jpeg. So, different file types and thus different resolutions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgOwner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:contentDescription="Image Owner"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_default_avator" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:text="User Name"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtVideoTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Video Title"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:textSize="10sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtVideoName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:text="Video Information"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    />
```

Comment: have you tried `android:scaleType="fitXY"`on the `ImageView`?

Comment: Yes, I did. It didn't look right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

Set imageview property like this

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgOwner"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="Image Owner"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```